# Filter git log by commit message and extract needed info into file

Tags: git

Some of my git commits have an id of task that is fixed in the commit
Example of a commit message:

```
Fix spelling error (fixes T15036)
```

so now, what I want to do is to be able to extract all the task ids within a time frame to be able to track what has been fixed within last week for example. The outcome I want to have is a string like this: "T15036, T15040, T14999..."

Is there a way to achieve it by using git commands only?

The closest I could get by using this:

```
git log --oneline  --since=2022/08/08 --grep=fixes > C:\repositories\GitLog.txt
```

It gives me all the commits that have fixes in them, but I still have to manually copy and paste the task ids.
Or maybe there are better approaches then what I do?

Thank you for taking your time to read my question and help me find a solution

Comment: piping into other utilities to format the output the specific way you need? `awk`, `sed`, etc etc etc

Comment: "using Git commands only": no. You need additional tools. Git is a set of tools, but it's not a full workshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @eftshift0 `sed` can do the job here, but unfortunately it goes beyond the scope of a pure git command ..

Here is an example of the command using a regular expression to only keep the issue tracker:

```
$ git log ... | sed -E 's/.*fixes (T[0-9]*).*/\1/' > GitLog.txt
```